# Verifying a call of a static void method with powermockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I am trying to capture the 'logError' method in a static class (in the sense of every method/field is static), and verify it has been called some number of times by other methods in the same class.

this method is:

```
public static void logError(Object message){
    LOGGER.error(message); // static logger
}
```

my attempt to test it:

```
@Test
public void errLogTest() throws Exception{
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(X.class);
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(X.class);
    X.logError(Mockito.anyString());
    X.open();
    X.open(); //should log error for opening twice
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(1));
}
```

My problem is, no matter how many times I specify, it passes. I removed mocking behavior and know for a fact the logger is called once, but I can have `PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(9001));` instead and it still passes. How do I test this?

Answer (score 7):

You're missing a line of code after `verifyStatic`. You're not telling PowerMock *what* to verify. You're also mocking *all* static methods of the class instead of just the one you don't want called.

```
@Test
public void errLogTest() throws Exception{
    PowerMockito.spy(X.class); //Used to be: PowerMockito.mockStatic(X.class);
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(X.class);
    X.logError(Mockito.anyString());
    X.open();
    X.open(); //should log error for opening twice
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(1));
    X.logError(Mockito.anyString()); //Now verifyStatic knows what to verify.
}
```

You may still need to do some debugging because, in my experience, setting up the expectations sometimes calls the underlying method anyway.

Here's the javadoc for `spy`: http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.5.4/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#spy(java.lang.Class)

Here's the javadoc for `verifyStatic`: http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.5.4/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#verifyStatic(org.mockito.verification.VerificationMode)

Comment: Done. I did not use the latest version because I have not re-tested with it.